# Difference between the way methods are called in smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

What is the difference between

```
 instance.totalSupply() vs instance.methods.totalSupply().call()
```

To my knowledge one is for truffle and the other is for web3.
But truffle also uses web3 then why can i not call the functions in a single way?

Answer (score 0):

From web3.js **version 1.0** it has been recommended to call smart contract functions like this

```
instance.methods.totalSupply().call()
```

Reference :  [methods](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12)

For earlier version ( < 1.0) we could call like

```
instance.totalSupply()
```

Note : [from docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/)

***This documentation is work in progress and web3.js 1.0 is not yet released! You can find the current documentation for web3 0.x.x at github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API.***

Comment: which web3 version is truffle using?

Comment: I am not sure. you can check it

Comment: to check the version use web3.version in truffle console (or develop)


@sharif2008 i read the doc , but I can't find where  it is said this is the recommended approach; is it possible it is just an alternative ?